# Can't find a ARGB PCB Connector

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, connector, rgb

I'm building a board to which I want to connect ARGB peripherals - strips, fans, etc. I have stumbled upon a big problem - I can't find those 3 pin connectors anywhere.

Regular pin strips don't work - the ARGB ones are rounded.

Do they have some unique name? Or are all the manufacturers using custom parts for them?

Ideally, I would like to have right-angled connectors, currently, I can't seem to find even the straight ones.

The best I could find are these - but they require manual snipping to size. They also are fragile and the extra pin has to be cut off as trying to pull it out ends up breaking the whole thing.

[image: Only thing I've found]

[image: Need to plug in this bad boy]

Comment: Rounded, as in machined-pin headers? Should be able to get those from the usual sources. I know Mill-Max makes them. But you can use square pins in most sockets, if they're the right size, even if they normally use round pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to look for is "machined pin" PCB pin strips.

> Ideally, I would like to have right-angled connectors

Digikey has 2 brands in stock: https://www.digikey.com/short/pr505c07

[image: Mill-Max 399-10-104-10-009000]

{Digikey}

Comment: The question has been edited to add a picture of the connector it needs to mate with; it looks like one pin is missing as a keying feature. It may not be possible to pull a pin out from those. Though you can probably snip one off with side cutters.

Comment: Thank you! Never would have guessed to search for "machined pin". Snipping will have to suffice.