# Which type of male header can connect to PC addressable RGB LED connectors?

Tags: led, identification, connector, rgb

I need to find the right connector, solderable on the surface of a PCB, that can mate with the cable shown in the picture below. This type of cable is commonly used of addressable RGB LED fixtures (probably WS2812b) used in "gamer" PC case customization.

[image: addressable RGB LED connector]

Initially, I tried mating my sample cable with standard male header, but the pins are too thick and squared; they do not fit. Seems that the specific piece of header required has thinner and round pins.

What is the designation of those specific male header pins so that I can order some?

Comment: A data sheet for the addressable LED would seem appropriate to identify and link in the question.

Comment: WS2812b probably. The three pins are 5V, DATA and GND. But this is not the core of the problem actually. I just need to make this cable connectable to my PCB; the signal part is already sorted out.

Comment: The answer in [Can't find a ARGB PCB Connector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/680152/101063) suggests you need to search for "machined pin" PCB pin strips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[4-positions, single-row straight male pin strip with circular posts on Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/449qrbjm)

[image: Pin strip with round pins]

{Source: [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/350-10-104-00-006000/4456125)}

Comment: ... and snip off the unrequired pin.